# Calculate div height on window resize using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I'm aiming to dynamically change the height of a div as the window is resized.

I'm successful when wrapping the jQuery in a function such as `$(window).smartresize(function () { }`, however, this breaks another area of the functionality.

**HMTL**

```
<section id="menu">

    <div class="menu-container">

        <ul class="menu__nav">
            <!-- menu nav  -->
        </ul>

        <div class="menu__main">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>

        <div class="menu__main">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>

        <div class="menu__main">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>

    </div>

</section>
```

**jQuery**

```
( function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var $mmenu = $('.menu__main');

        if ($mmenu.length > 0) {

            var $mnav = $('.menu__nav'),
                $mnav_a = $mnav.find('a'),
                m = parseInt($mnav.outerHeight(true), 10),
                $contain = $mmenu.closest('.menu-container'),
                h = 0,
                l = 0;

            $mmenu.not(':eq(0)').hide();
            $mmenu.eq(0).addClass('active');
            $mnav_a.eq(0).addClass('active');

            $mmenu.each(function(z) {

                var $this = $(this);

                $this.css('height','auto');

                $this.css({
                    zIndex: z+1,
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: m + "px",
                    left: l,
                    height: (parseInt($this.outerHeight(false), 10) + m) + "px"
                });

                l = l - $this.outerWidth();

            });

            $contain.height($mmenu.eq(0).height());

            $mnav_a.on('click', function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                var $this = $(this);

                if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {

                    $mmenu.stop(true, true);

                    $mnav_a.removeClass('active');
                    $this.addClass('active');

                    $mmenu.filter($('.active'))
                        .removeClass('active')
                        .fadeOut(250)
                        .animate({left:l+"px"}, 250);

                    var $target = $mmenu.filter($this.attr('href'));

                    $contain.animate({height:$target.height()}, 250);

                    $target.addClass('active')
                        .fadeIn(250)
                        .animate({left:0}, 250);
                }

                $this.blur();
            });
        }
    });

} ) ( jQuery );
```

This is the area I'm most interested in improving:

```
$mmenu.each(function(z) {

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.css('height','auto');

    $this.css({
        zIndex: z+1,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: m + "px",
        left: l,
        height: (parseInt($this.outerHeight(false), 10) + m) + "px"
    });

    l = l - $this.outerWidth();

});

$contain.height($mmenu.eq(0).height());
```

Please let me know if you require further information, hopefully there's an easy fix, thank you

Comment: Would using something like the .on() method work?? So, .on( "resize", function() {} or .on( "smartresize", function() {}

Answer (score 0):

I think with you can resize with CSS, using percent of window. You can define percent for some especifics size of devices. I just create this css for example of funcionality.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #divMenu {
        width:40%;
        height:70%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    #divMenu {
        width:70%;
        height:80%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    #divMenu {
        width:50%;
        height:50%;
    }
}
```

Sorry, for my poor english.

Comment: Thank you Rafael. Unfortunately Media Queries won't work in this example as the divs will differ in height depending on their content...and the content will change over time as well. It needs to be dynamic